# pulling data out of mysql creating array with array structure

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a MySql database with three columns: skp, date and usr.  For each skp and date pair there are several usr(s).  Is there a query that will pull the data out with the following array structure:

```
array[i]['skp']
array[i]['date']
array[i]['usr'][j]
```

I'm wondering if somehow using a group by would work?

Comment: You need to construct the array you want by combining data from the related rows. MySQL APIs won't create the array you want directly.

Comment: Need much more to answer this. For one, Databases do not contain columns,,,  Databases contain tables.. Tables contain columns (and rows)  so.. please show the schema for the tables you intend to use (you cant get that by doing `describe tablename;` via mysql prompt or in PHPMyadmin

Comment: You could use `GROUP_CONCAT(usr) AS usr`, and the in the PHP code you can use `explode(',', $row['usr'])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `GROUP_CONCAT`.

```
SELECT skp, date, GROUP_CONCAT('usr') AS usr
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY skp, date
```

Then when retrieving, you can split the `usr` column into an array.

```
$array = ();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $row['usr'] = explode(',', $row['usr']);
    $array[] = $row;
}
```